# Save datefield from template: error "value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."

Tags: django, date, datetime, input, format

Now i have to insert data in `AAAA-MM-DD` format, if i want insert `%m/%d/%Y`, `%m/%d/%y` format, what i can do? 
Thanks i'm new on Django.

I have template where i insert Data:

**TEMPLATE**

```
<tr>
    <td>N_Prova</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="nprova"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Date Analysis</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="date_analysis" /></td>
</tr>
```

**MODEL**

```
class Analysis(models.Model):
    nprova = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    date_analysis = models.DateField(null=True)
```

**VIEW**

```
    def addanalisi(request):

        if 'save' in request.POST:
            print("save is in request post")

            newanal = analysis(nprova=nprova,data_analysis=date_analysis)
            newanal.save()

            print(nprova,data_analysis)
            return redirect('/listanalysis/')

        analysis = Analysis.objects.all()
        template = 'italgraniti/addanalysis.html'
        context_instance = RequestContext(request)

return render_to_response(template, {'form': form, 'analysis' : analysis}, context_instance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) function.

So in your view, you want to have:

```
date = time.strptime(request.POST['date_analysis'], "%m/%d/%Y")   
newanal = analysis(nprova=request.POST['nprova'],data_analysis=date)
newanal.save()
```

Comment: ok, now expect right format,  but it return " Exception Value: 
expected string or bytes-like object". what does it means?

Answer (score 2):

You should create `ModelForm` based on your `Model`. The form will [automatically convert](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data) the date into a Python `datetime.date` object.

forms.py:

```
from .models import Analysis


class AnalysisForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_analysis = form.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y',
                                                '%m/%d/%y',])
    class Meta:
        model = Analysis
```

views.py:

```
from .forms import AnalysisForm


def addanalisi(request):  
    form = AnalysisForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid:
        form.save()
    return render(request, template, {'form':form})
```

[docs_about_modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) and [input_formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats)